# I want to ssh using shell script but it does not work

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, freebsd, ssh-keys

I have a virtual machine running FreeBSD and I set it up so I can access it headless via ssh. However I do not want to type the commands everytime. So I created a script file `SSH-BSD`, chmodded it. It contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo `ssh -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1`
```

When I launch the script it connects, prompting me for password. However when I type it in, it just hangs and does not nothing. Mind you, if I type the exact thing that is in the script, then I log into the machine just fine.

So I thought, maybe for the script to run this way, my machine needs to be authenticated. So I created keys via `ssh-keygen` and then `ssh-copy-id` to VM. This works great and no longer requires me to type in the password but still when I launch the script, it just hangs.

I don't do bash scripts so I am probably unaware of the limitations, can someone please enlighten me? Thank you.

Comment: For a one liner like that you could also set up a bash alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `echo`

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1
```

This should work fine.

Comment: sweet it works. I knew i wasn't doing something right. what's the difference between using this with/without `echo`?

Comment: In BASH, the ` mark means to run the command inside and get the output. So if you use echo, it will redirect all the output you want to echo but not the standard output.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. i'll read up on bash scripting more.